# Summernote Ruby Gem not working with form (RoR)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have recently included the Summernote gem in my Gemfile and included all necessary lines in .js and .css files (intructions found here http://rorlab.github.io/summernote-rails/)

I want to use Summernote to edit my "steps" text_area in my Recipe database. The form works perfectly without Summernote (see image below)

[image]

However when I assign my field as follows with added 'summernote' class:

```
<%= f.text_field :steps, class: 'summernote', placeholder: "Add step", id: "add_steps" %>
```

I am shown the summernote output but my text inout is missing and the submit button will not work.

[image]

Any Ideas?

In the instructions in the link I was told to add to the recipe.js.coffee script. I added the following:

```
summer_note = $('add_steps')

summer_note.summernote

height:300  
 toolbar: [
             ['insert', ['picture', 'link']], // no insert buttons
             ["table", ["table"]], 
             ["style", ["style"]], 
             ["fontsize", ["fontsize"]], 
             ["color", ["color"]], 
             ["style", ["bold", "italic", "underline", "clear"]], 
             ["para", ["ul", "ol", "paragraph"]], 
             ["height", ["height"]], 
             ["help", ["help"]]
         ]

summer_note.code summer_note.val()


summer_note.closest('form').submit ->
 alert $('add_steps').code()[0]
summer_note.val summer_note.code()[0]
true
```

And my Javascript in the _step_form.html.erb file is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.summernote').summernote({
  toolbar: [
    //['style', ['style']], // no style button
    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    //['insert', ['picture', 'link']], // no insert buttons
    //['table', ['table']], // no table button
    //['help', ['help']] //no help button
  ]
});
});
</script>
```

I am a newbie to RoR so any help appreciated! Thank you. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a hashtag to the 'add_steps' ID.

That is, change this selector:

```
summer_note = $('add_steps')
```

to this:

```
summer_note = $('#add_steps')
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it still doesn't seem to want to work. The text is actually displaying within the text editor like in the first image now but the submit button does not seem to work if I make any changes. hmmm